# Spring Boot Admin Journal history

Tags: history, journal, spring-boot-admin

Is there any way to keep the history about application status changing in Spring Boot Admin Journal page after restart the Spring Boot Admin server? 
There is history about all the status changes of all registered applications, but if i restart the admin server, the history disapears and start to recording changes since the moment of startup. Is there a way to keep the history in this page permanently ? even if the spring boot admin server get restarted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. You can implement `JournaledEventStore` yourself using your favourite persistence technology or you setup SBA to use hazelcast and configure hazelcast so that the data gets persisted.

The sample for hazelcast is labeled 'clustering' but you also can run a single node. See http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.4/#clustering-support

The sample doesn't configure the data to be persisted. You need to look that up.

Comment: Ok so I include hazelcast dependency in my pom and enable hazelcast in my application. And the question now is how to enable the journal data in spring boot admin panel to be persisted :)